# Problema al usar graficos chartJS en Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, chart.js

Estoy usando la libreria [vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#chart-with-api-data) para realizar graficos de tortas(Pie) el problema que tengo es que obtengo datos dinamicos de la base de datos de la siguiente manera que son registros de tipos de habitaciones.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al componente de vue lo llamo de la siguiente manera

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div :class="[menu_theme]">
      <div class="box-header">
          <h3 class="text-center">{{'Habitaciones disponibles por tipo'}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="box-body">
          <div class="chart">
              <pie-chart :chartdata="chartData" :options="chartOptions" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 100%;"></pie-chart>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

el script que uso en el componente

```js
<script>
require('../../../css/animation.css');
import { alert } from 'vue-strap';
import lineChart from './line.vue';
import barChart from './bar.vue';
import pieChart from './pie.vue';

export default {
    props: ['theme', 'permission'],
    data() {
        return {
            
            typeAlert: 'danger',
            alertMessage: '',
            showRight: false,
            showLoader: 'none',
            labelsRoom: ['Disponibles', 'Ocupados','Limpieza', 'Mantenimiento'],
            labelsRoomType: [],
            dateRoom: [],
            dateRoomType: [],
            chartData: null,
            chartOptions: null
        }
    },
    components: {
        alert,
        lineChart,
        barChart,
        pieChart,
    },
    computed: {
        menu_theme() {
            if(this.theme === 'Azul'){
                return 'box box-primary';
            }
            if(this.theme === 'Rojo'){
                return 'box box-danger';
            }
            if(this.theme === 'Verde'){
                return 'box box-success';
            }
            return 'box box-success';
        },
        permission_write() {
            return this.permission;
        },
    },
    created(){
    },
    mounted() {
        
        this.getTypeRooms();

    },
    methods: {
        getTypeRooms(){
            axios.get(`/api/v1/room/type`)
                .then(response => {
                    let rooms = response.data.dateValue;
                    let labelsAux = [];
                    let dataAux = [];
                    rooms.map((item)=>{
                        labelsAux.push(item.name);
                        dataAux.push(item.total);
                    })
                    this.chartData = {
                        labels: labelsAux,
                        datasets: [{
                            borderWidth: 1,
                            borderColor: ['#00a65a','#f56954' , '#00c0ef','#f39c12'],
                            backgroundColor : ['#00a65a','#f56954' , '#00c0ef','#f39c12'],
                            data: dataAux
                        }]
                    },
                    this.chartOptions = {
                        legend: {
                            display: true
                        },
                        responsive: true,
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        datasetFill: false
                    
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    this.errors.push(e)
                });
        },
        showMessage(type, message) {
            this.typeAlert = type;
            this.showRight = true;
            this.alertMessage = message;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style src="../../../sass/main.scss" lang="scss"></style>
```

EL componente Pie.vue (grafico de torta)

```js
<script>
  import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'
  export default {
    extends: Pie,
    props: {
      chartdata: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
      },
      options: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
      console.log(this.chartdata);
    },
    watch: {
      chartData () {
        this.$data._chart.update()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

al parecer todo funciona bien estoy pasando los datos bien al chartData y options solo que no muestra el grafico o  no me renderiza los datos en el grafico de tortas y no se donde es problema tampoco me marca error en la consola
[image: datos asignados a las variables chartData y Options]

el resultado me muestra en blanco[image: Resultado Obtenido]

Comment: Como estas poniendo la etiqueta del gráfico en la parte HTML?, la etiqueta del plugin debe ir sola, sin estar dentro de las <template> de vue, por ejemplo para un gráfico de barras solo basta con poner `<Bar />`

Comment: el problema que tengo es al momento cambiar los datos  para graficar por si los mantego estaticos me muestra la grafica pero como obtengo de la base de datos ahi es el problema no me muestra nada

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener un método que renderice nuevamente tus datos cada vez que cambian, con el `this.$data._chart.update()` no basta siempre, lo ideal seria que tengas un metodo `load()` como el siguiente.

```
    load()
    {
        this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
    }
```

Este método lo debes llamar al momento que cambian tus datos, es necesario para que el `charts` pueda leer y mostrar bien lo nuevo que le llega, lo ideal seria que uses un `ref` en tu etiqueta `<pie-chart ref="pie">` y llames al metodo `load` de este componente cada vez que se actualizan los datos, por ejemplo:

```
this.$refs.pie.load()
```